# Raid 6 with HP P421?

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-smart-array, raid6, raid-controller

I cant figure out if I need to buy a licens key to enable Raid 6 for this raid controller? I can't find where to buy one and I find pages where it says that its now free.

sudo hpssacli ctrl slot=1 show detail gives me:

```
Smart Array P421 in Slot 1
Bus Interface: PCI
Slot: 1
Serial Number: XXXXX
Cache Serial Number: XXXXX
RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Disabled
Controller Status: OK
Hardware Revision: B
Firmware Version: 3.42
Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
Post Prompt Timeout: 15 secs
Cache Board Present: True
Cache Status: OK
Drive Write Cache: Disabled
Total Cache Size: 1024 MB
Total Cache Memory Available: 816 MB
No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
SSD Caching RAID5 WriteBack Enabled: False
SSD Caching Version: 1
Cache Backup Power Source: Capacitors
Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
SATA NCQ Supported: True
Spare Activation Mode: Activate on physical drive failure (default)
Controller Temperature (C): 58
Cache Module Temperature (C): 30
Capacitor Temperature  (C): 26
Number of Ports: 2 External only
Encryption Supported: False
Driver Name: hpsa
Driver Version: 3.4.0
Driver Supports HP SSD Smart Path: False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for another license to enable RAID6 functionality on an HP Smart Array P42x RAID controller. It was included after a certain release of the firmware. The current controller firmware is [version 6.34](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5212601&swItemId=MTX_13fcbd530be24670b72b5c96fe&swEnvOid=4103#tab-history).

You can download the firmware for this from HP.

Go to http://hp.com and select "Support".

Enter your product's name in the provided field...

[image]

Verify the product and click on its link.

[image]

Select your operating system, and you'll be presented with downloads specific to your RAID controller.

[image]

Follow the installation instructions for the firmware download you end up selecting.

Comment: Amazing effort, the link was all I needed!

Comment: HP seem to have moved all server support to hpe.com.  Right now the best steps seem to be to browse to https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/home/result?qt=P421 (P421 being the controller model), click Drivers and Software, select Software Type: Firmware, and sort by date.

Answer (score 1):

It is free in the latest versions of the firmware (since 4.68). However, you may need a licence from HP to legally download the required update.

Comment: I have been looking for this firmware for hours, where can I find it and how do I install it?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that version added the HP Smart Array Advanced Pack (SAAP), which formerly required a licence, and - as best I can tell from https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03245319 - provides the support for RAID 6.  Note, I was able to download the firmware update from the above answer without needing to sign in.